# Inkscape Issues Importing PDF Text: Case and 'fi' Rendering

Tags: inkscape, fonts, text, pdf, import

I am trying to make minor edits to an existing PDF that I have imported into Inkscape, but am having issues with the rendering of the text from the PDF.

1. Letters that are combined in certain, such as 'i' disappear so 'fi' becomes 'f '.
2. Certain sections of text become random cases. This I can correct manually by changing the case, but it is inconvenient.

Image example disappearing 'i' (1), original PDF above and Inkscape import below:
[image: Example disappearing 'i', original PDF above and Inkscape import below.]

Image example of random case rendering (2), original PDF above and Inkscape import below:
[image: Example of random case rendering, original PDF above and Inkscape import below.]

Any suggestions to address these issues or import the PDF differently?

Comment: The "fi" is a ligature which is being replaced with just f, no ligature. fl, tt, etc are other ligatures which any be effected as well. The case.. hard to say. It *may* have been keyed in that way and then an app used to just make it all uppercase. Are you using the same *exact* font and it contains ligatures?

Answer (score 1):

The font is replacing an f and an i with an 'fi' ligature, but it appears Inkscape doesn't understand this and puts in an 'f'. I don't have any suggestion but maybe see if you use Adobe Acrobat on it. I haven't used it much but it has best-in-class pdf support, I've sometimes found Adobe Reader can display pdfs properly other apps can't get right.

Comment: Inkscape does generally support ligatures though.  Perhaps the OP doesn't have the right fonts installed.  Maybe some kind of font substitution is going on here.

Comment: That's also possible. The basic version of Georgia (that's the font here) doesn't do ligature substitution, although it has ligature characters. Maybe copy those characters in from the character panel? Or maybe the font is Georgia Pro?